# Criar relatório com código de barras

Tags: jasper-reports, código-de-barras

Preciso criar um relatório no Jasper Studio com código de barras porém não estou conseguindo de nenhuma forma ler o código de barras que o relatório esta gerando, minha dúvida é, qual o padrão de código de barras que devo utilizar, e como devo configurá-lo no Jasper Studio para que a pistola de leitura de código de barras consiga lê-lo.

- Estou utilizando atualmente o Jasper Studio 5.6.0 (A ferramenta que
  estou utilizando permite apenas até a versão 5.x do Jasper Studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei uma solução aqui que funcionou neste [leitor online de código de barras](https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/).

```
<!-- Coloque isso após a tag de abertura <jasperReport> -->
<style name="Barcode" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#000066" backcolor="#FFFFFF" fill="Solid" hAlign="Left" vAlign="Top" markup="styled" fontName="SansSerif" fontSize="11"/>
<!-- ... -->
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement style="Barcode" x="230" y="43" width="78" height="38" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="e70dd866-d0a9-4b34-8fb1-0f0b04c9dcf3"/>
            <jr:Code128 xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$F{nomedocampo}]]></jr:codeExpression>
            </jr:Code128>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Quanto ao código que se deve usar a [documentação do Barcode](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/barcode4j/index.html) esclarece:

> Some of linear symbologies are highly standardized, some others are niche-oriented, most of them presenting mixed features. Below are few examples:
>
> 1. Universal Product Code (UPC) - International Standard ISO/IEC 15420. There are 5 versions of the UPC symbology designed for future industry requirements: UPC A, B, C, D, E.
> 2. Codabar - Outdated format used in libraries, blood banks and on air waybills. Not standardized.
> 3. Code 25 – Interleaved 2 of 5 - Used in wholesales and libraries. International standard ISO/IEC 16390
> 4. Code 39 - International standard ISO/IEC 16388
> 5. Code 128 – International Standard ISO/IEC 15417
> 6. EAN-8 - International Standard ISO/IEC 15420
> 7. EAN-13 - International Standard ISO/IEC 15420
> 8. JAN - Available for Japan, compatible with EAN-13 (ISO/IEC 15420)

Dai tem que ver quais o aparelho suporta, normalmente isso é dito na embalagem. Mas sendo os citados acima os principais deve funcionar.

Créditos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612910/jasperreports-barcode-generation-with-barcode4j-library-depencies